# Do wireless devices such as smartphones transmit beacon equivalent frames such as APs do?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop, wireless-access-point, mobile-phone

Can they be made to announce their presence somehow using layer 2 frames without them be connected to any network or access point?

Can their MAC address be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, Yes, wireless devices such as smartphones can and often do transmit 802.11 frames that can allow other devices to detect them and learn their MAC addresses, even when those devices are not connected to any access point. But they're typically not Beacons *per se*, but things like Probe Requests (active scan packets).

For example, if your smartphone isn't associated to any network, it's probably going through its list of previously-joined networks, scanning (transmitting Probe Request frames) to see if any of those known networks are now available to be joined. Those Probe Request frames not only leak the device's MAC address, but also leak the names of networks it is looking for (such as the names of your home and work networks).

Various peer-to-peer networking modes, including ad hoc (IBSS) mode, Wi-Fi Direct, and Apple's AWDL, may cause wireless device to transmit real Beacons or packets very similar to real Beacons. Also, putting a smartphone in mobile hotspot (Wi-Fi tethering) mode makes it act as pretty much a full-fledged AP, so it transmits real Beacons.

To see what packets a device around you is transmitting, run an 802.11 monitor mode packet sniffer. Wireshark can do this as long as you have a supported wireless interface to run it on. This is supported under OS X on all built-in Mac Wi-Fi interfaces. It may be trickier to get this working under Windows or Linux.

iOS 8 and later contain MAC address protection features where, when they transmit Probe Requests, they use a temporary, randomly generated MAC address, to try to keep your device's real MAC address a secret when you're just walking around the city with the device in your pocket.